# How to listen to socket emit on sails.io.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm using *Sails 0.11* in my back-end, and *angularjs* in the front-end.

I have a **TwitterController** in sails with the following code, to open a stream with the Twitter Streaming API (this uses the node module *twit*):

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit(sails.config.twit);

var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {
    track: ['apple']
});

module.exports = {
    open: function(req, res) {
        if (!req.isSocket) {
            return res.badRequest();
        }

        var socketId = sails.sockets.id(req.socket);

        stream.start();

        stream.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
            sails.log.debug('Tweet received.');
            sails.sockets.emit(socketId, 'tweet', tweet);
        });
    }
};
```

In my front-end (with the *angular-sails* module):

```
$sails.get('/twitter/open').then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp.status);
}, function(resp) {
  alert('Houston, we got a problem!');
});
```

This of course reaches my back-end controller, and the streaming starts, but how do I listen to the

> sails.sockets.emit(socketId, 'tweet', tweet);

issued by the server?.

I'd appreciate any help here!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following wZVanG's answer. This is how I did it, using the *angular-sails* angular module.

```
$sails.get('/twitter/open').then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp.status);
}, function(resp) {
  alert('Houston, we got a problem!');
});

$sails.on('tweet', function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

That logs every tweet received to the browser's console.

Answer (score 3):

Sails library creates a global variable "io", so you can use also:

```
io.socket.on("tweet", function(data){})
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. I'm posting my own answer, which uses io.socket.on, but with the angular-sails module